# Coulmns align on Windows, but not on macOS

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a very simple layout. On Windows, the columns align, but on macOS, they do not! How do I fix this? I am using the PySimpleGUIQt version.

Windows
[image: Windows]

macOS
[image: macOS]

```
def display_stats(character):
    column_1 = [
        [sg.Text('Birth/Family', background_color='gold', justification='c')],
        [sg.Text('Species'), sg.Text(character.species, background_color='lightblue'), sg.Text('Gender'),
         sg.Text(character.gender, background_color='lightblue')],
        [sg.Text('Birthdate'),
         sg.Text(f'{character.birth_month} {character.birth_day}',
                 background_color='lightblue'),
         sg.Text('Sunsign'), sg.Text(f'{character.sunsign}', background_color='lightblue')
         ]
    ]

    column_2 = [
        [sg.Text('Appearance', background_color='gold')],
        [sg.Text('Height'), sg.Text(character.height, background_color='lightblue'), sg.Text('Frame'),
         sg.Text(character.frame, background_color='lightblue'), sg.Text('Weight'),
         sg.Text(character.weight, background_color='lightblue')],
        [sg.Text('Size'), sg.Text(character.size, background_color='lightblue'), sg.Text('Comeliness'),
         sg.Text(character.comeliness, background_color='lightblue'), sg.Text('Handedness'),
         sg.Text(character.handedness, background_color='lightblue')],
        [sg.Text('Physical', background_color='gold', justification='c')],
        [sg.Text('Strength'), sg.Text(character.strength, background_color='lightblue'), sg.Text('Endurance'),
         sg.Text(character.endurance, background_color='lightblue'), sg.Text('Dexterity'),
         sg.Text(character.dexterity, background_color='lightblue')],
        [sg.Text('Agility'), sg.Text(character.agility, background_color='lightblue'), sg.Text('Speed'),
         sg.Text(character.speed, background_color='lightblue'), sg.Text('Eyesight'),
         sg.Text(character.eyesight, background_color='lightblue')],
        [sg.Text('Hearing'), sg.Text(character.hearing, background_color='lightblue'), sg.Text('Smell/Taste'),
         sg.Text(character.smell_taste, background_color='lightblue'), sg.Text('Touch'),
         sg.Text(character.touch, background_color='lightblue')],
        [sg.Text('Voice'), sg.Text(character.voice, background_color='lightblue')],
        [sg.Text('Personality', background_color='gold', justification='c')],
        [sg.Text('Intelligence'), sg.Text(character.intelligence, background_color='lightblue'), sg.Text('Aura'),
         sg.Text(character.aura, background_color='lightblue')],
        [sg.Text('Will'), sg.Text(character.will, background_color='lightblue'), sg.Text('Morality'),
         sg.Text(character.morality, background_color='lightblue')],
        [sg.Text('Piety'), sg.Text(character.piety, background_color='lightblue')]
    ]

    layout = [
        [sg.Column(column_1)],
        [sg.Column(column_2)],
        [sg.OK(auto_size_button=False), sg.Button('Save', auto_size_button=False),
         sg.Button('Re-roll', auto_size_button=False)]
    ]

    window = sg.Window('Generated Character', layout, finalize=True, size=(800, 600), font=('Baskerville', 25))
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Save' or event == 'Re-roll':
        window.close()
        return event
    # End program if user closes window or
    # presses the OK button
    window.close()
```

I expect the same code (using the same underlying framework) to work in the same (or at least a very **similar**) fashion! The alignment should not be wildly different!

Comment: The macOS version looks like it's terminal based.

Comment: They are both being ran from within PyCharm. It is the exact same script.

Comment: I'm just saying what it looks like, in case that's a clue that helps you. I don't know anything about PyCharm specifically or how it's implemented.